# How to sale Solana NFT which has minted with my own contract?

Tags: marketplace, solana, candy-machine

I have minted NFTS with my own contract on Solana blockchain.
I am going to sell these NFTS on Marketplace but marketplaces need candy machine addresses or hash-list.
I have no candy machine address and have no idea about the hash-list.
I need sincere help from the smart developers of Solana.

Comment: David, which marketplace is asking explicitly for a candy-machine address? Can you update your question with an example?

Comment: Magic Eden is typical marketplace. Solanart and solsea also require it for verifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the Candy Machine in order to sell or verify your collection on other marketplaces. You're misunderstanding the verification forms.

On [Magic Eden](https://airtable.com/shroOLXKGFsfhVWfd) verification you can just say "no" and provide the hash list, and this works the same on other marketplaces.

[image]

Now for your second question, the Hash List is the list of mint addresses of the NFTs, their addresses on the blockchain. The Candy Machine keeps the hash list on-chain that's why they ask if you have it, so they can get the list from there, but it is optional.

If you minted your NFTs yourself then you must have the mint addresses somewhere, or you can get it from your own wallet account.

You have to create a file with the NFTs mint addresses, like this one. The file format might change depending on the Marketplace.

```json
[
        "MINT HASH",
        "MINT HASH",
        "MINT HASH"
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I have one more question. If I don't mint all nfts in once, then how can I provide hashlist to magic eden.

Comment: @DavidNasaw I couldn't find guide for it in the docs, you should ask it in their Discord if you want to be sure, however this is perfectly supported on other marketplaces, should be on theirs too.